# WPF Docking Control Recommendation

Tags: wpf, size, docking

Is there a Docking control that does a good job and provide good options for ReSizing? I want some docked windows to be of fixed width/Height and others to resize. Most of the Docking controls I have tried, doesn't provide good option to set minimum/maximum width or even specify starting width.

To put my question other way, if I create a SplitPanel, I want one Pane to have specified Height/Width, and the other Pane to occupy the remainder of the space. General recommendation I have received is that you need to set relative size, between panes, and let the docking control, figure out the size. It is not sufficient enough in my case.

There have been discussions on this board about WPF Docking library, but none of them address this specific issue.

I have tried ActiPro and Telerik Docking controls, without success. If you have tried something which you like, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free docking control called [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  I personally use [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/Default.aspx) docking control, and it has done everything I have asked of it so far.  Hopefully one of those will work out for you.

Comment: +1 for Infragistics. I had a great experience with their control set for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for the same you can try

[Component One WPF Controls](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWPF/)